# How to enable antialiasing on java swing GUI

Tags: java, swing, scala, user-interface, antialiasing

I am using scala and java swing for the UI. I want to enable **antialiasing** for all

```
javax.swing.JComponent
```

Currently I use the following trait

```
trait Antialising extends javax.swing.JComponent{

   override def paint(g: Graphics): Unit = {
       g.asInstanceOf[Graphics2D].setRenderingHint(java.awt.RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, java.awt.RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON)
       super.paint(g)
   }
}
```

and initialize all components with the addition "with Antialiasing" like for example

```
val fileMenu = new JMenu("File") with Antialising
```

**Question: Is there a way to enable antialiasing globally?**

(I already tried following which is not working)

```
System.setProperty("awt.useSystemAAFontSettings","lcd");
System.setProperty("swing.aatext", "true");
```

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).